# How to get the invader moving left to right in java

Tags: java, object, game-physics

I'm creating a small space invaders project and I have the aliens constantly in a left to right loop. When they hit the end of the screen they repaint on the right side going again left to right. I have set the window size already and I have looked at various tutorials on how to make space invaders in Java, however most of them say the same thing that I have tried. Is it possible someone can point out where I am going wrong with my coding so that I know how to fix it.

This is the code for the alien class. There are different aliens, however all the classes look pretty much the same as this one:

```
package spaceinvaders2;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

class Alien extends MoveObject 
{
    Image Alien = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("alien.gif")).getImage();
Alien(int x, int y, int w, int h) 
{
    super(x, y);
    bounds.width = w;
    bounds.height = h;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    System.out.println("Alien generated");
    bounds.x = bounds.x - 2;

    if ((bounds.x + bounds.width)< 0)
    {
        bounds.x = 750;
        dead = false;
    }

    g.drawImage(Alien,bounds.x,bounds.y,bounds.width, bounds.height, this);
}
}
```

Edit: My paint method is being called in the main game functionality part where it draws all the graphics. The drawing isn't the problem it is the movement of the alien which is in this class.

Comment: Can you specify what is wrong with the movement of the alien? From looking at your code I would say that the movement speed depends on the frame rate which might not be constant, but maybe that is not a problem.

Comment: It's difficult to provide feedback without knowing more about the code, but basically in your top level component, you need to capture the key stroke (no, really ;)), probably using something like the key bindings API & adjust the movement direction parameter. Depending on what you want to achieve, you could keep adding/subtracting the direction until a new key stroke is registered

Answer (score 2):

I think the paint Method ist just running once.
You have to add a thread to call the paint() method periodi.

Comment: I already have that in my main game class. All the paint methods are being called there to draw the graphics

Comment: Yes, I have ran the game, the main class repaints every 8 seconds to move them across the screen right to left. I am trying to move them left to right once they hit the screen boundaries rather than just an constant loop of right to left.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the Alien a `direction` attribute (+1 or -1) which tells it which direction it is moving in. When it is about to go off-screen, flip the direction. For example, if the direction was +1 change it to -1 and vice versa.

Here is a simple example I created:

```
public class Alien extends JPanel 

    private int x = 5;
    private int y = 5;
    private int direction = 1;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.clearRect(x, y, getWidth(), getHeight());

        // draw the alien.
        g.drawRect(x, y, 10, 10);

        // move it
        x = x + 5 * direction;

        // is it about to go off-screen?
        if (x < 0 || x + 10 > getWidth()) {
            // change the direction
            direction *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you want the aliens to move from left to right once they hit the screen boundaries, instead of re-entering at the other side.

The solution is simple, you have to keep track of the direction of the alien. An easy way to do this is to make it's step size a variable.

You give your Alien class a `step` member like this:

```
int step = -2;
```

Then:

```
bounds.x = bounds.x + direction;

if ((bounds.x + bounds.width)< 0)
{
    step = +2;
}
else if ((bounds.x - bound.width) > 750)
{
    step = -2;
}
dead = false;

g.drawImage(Alien,bounds.x,bounds.y,bounds.width, bounds.height, this);
```

Off-topic, I think the `dead = false` doesn't belong in your `paint` method.

Comment: Thank you, now it moves left to right but doesn't stick to the screen size so I think with some messing around it may eventually work. Thank you once again

Comment: @user1134409 You're welcome. There was a little mistake in my sample code: the second condition should have been `(bounds.x - bound.width) > 750` (minus instead of plus). Have fun coding!